# What is wrong with my PHP Send Mail Function below?

Tags: php, email

What is wrong with my PHP Send Mail function? I am hosting this script on a live server.

```
$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: exampleemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: exampleemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){}
else{
echo "Email sending failed";
 }
```

I keep receiving the "Email sending Failed" message.

Comment: has the server been configured to send email and have you verified this?

Comment: @castis Yeah I think the server is configured to send emails as I have used this method before a while back and it worked

Comment: Your code Works in other hosts Paste your code here http://phpcodepad.com/ and check your spam box or inbox...

Comment: Make sure Your current code is this....

Comment: @Nawin It works on phpcodepad.com. I think my server is not configured correctly then. Thanks for that!